# Rest framework serializer always returns False for is_valid

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My serializer, quite basic:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date_time = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

wanted to try out from shell but I get `False` each time I try to check it for validation.

```
> import datetime
> s=TestSerializer({'date_time': datetime.datetime(year=2012,month=12,day=12)}
> s.data
{'date_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 0, 0)}
> s.is_valid()
False
> s.errors
{u'non_field_errors': [u'No input provided']}
```

Why is this? What is going on?

Comment: I end up here with oposit problem. Serializer always valid,, because mixing Serializer with ModelSerializer....

Comment: @andi I think you should make a new question with your code included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to specify data explicitly:

```
s = TestSerializer(data={'date_time': datetime.datetime(year=2012,month=12,day=12)}
```

Otherwise it assumes that the first argument is a model instance but that's not the case here.

Comment: It would seem so. but when the `data` is given explicitly then the s.data value gives `None`. When I did this:

Comment: @Salyangoz that is expected behaviour to prevent accidentally accessing data before validating. As the documentation says you need to call `is_valid()` before `s.data` gets a value. Before that it'll indeed be `None`.